# Boto3.resource seems slow

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am running the below code, where I dynamically populate the region. The below code takes a little long to execute. In Lambda, the time shows 11600ms. Is it normal or is there a way to speed it up?

```
ec2_r = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=aws_regions)
  DO SOMETHING
```

Comment: You're sure it's exactly this line that has the delay?  For best results, you should probably try to build an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can use to see if they can duplicate the behavior you see.

Comment: Troubleshooting tip: increasing the amount of memory allocated to your lambda function also increases the available CPU resources (e.g. allocating 4x the memory ≈ allocating 4x as much CPU capacity). This can be an effective way of determining whether you are slowed down by the CPU demand of your code (if it gets proportionally faster), or by something else (if it doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

Execution of a Lambda function depends on "Memory" that you allocate to the function.

The memory is not just CPU Memory, it also loosely correlates to the actual resource your code will be running on. Think of it like EC2 machines with t2 micro vs t2 large.

You can also enable X-Ray on Lambda to see if there is anything else.